# Microsoft Office alt-key-driven symmetrical resizing and cropping lost?

Tags: macos, ms-office

I couldn't find any info on regular Google search on this so I take my chances here.

For a long time, MS Office image and shape handling has featured "symmetrical" changes to an object when manipulated with the alt key pressed (at least on the Mac). For instance, dragging an object handle in one direction caused the object to grow/shrink equally in the opposite direction when the alt key was pressed.

As of a recent update to MS Office 2016 for Mac (16.16.21 (200413)), this functionality seems to be gone. I wonder if anyone knows why or whether it is replaced by some other key combo or tool?

Answer (score 0):

The change to this functionality apparently happened earlier than with update 16.16.21, but anyway the key to use for symmetrical transformations of objects in Office 2016 for Mac is now **the ctrl key**.